# JS cannot post or getElement

Tags: javascript, html

Here's Our code

```
                        <div class="col-2">
                            <div class="input-group">
                                <label class="label">Name</label>
                                <input id="name" class="input--style-4" type="text">
                            </div>
```

and JS

```
var btn = document.getElementById("register");
var email = document.getElementById("email");
var pw = document.getElementById("pw");
var date = document.getElementById("date").value;
var gender = document.getElementById("gender");
var name = document.getElementById("name");
var number = document.getElementById("number"); 

btn.onclick=function(){
    if(gender.checked) gender="m";
    else gender="f";
    $.ajax({
        url: 'register.php',
        type: 'POST',
        data: {
            email: email.value,
            pw: pw.value,
            date: date,
            gender: gender,
            name: name.value,
            number: number.value
        },
```

Keep sending null for name value.

What's the problem?

Comment: Please add a [mcve] that shows the actual problem.

Comment: Why don't you use jQuery for everything if it's already available (`$.ajax()`)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be make a  FormData object like this :

var form_data = new FormData();

and append your data form_data.append("email", email.value);

then send the form-data object like this :

```
        data: form_data,
        method: 'POST',
```

Comment: we need to use existing form...T.T

Comment: there is no problem, it can be used with it